# Wordpress admin screen not working properly in IE6

Tags: wordpress, internet-explorer-6

I need a blog to function on IE6 for a client (company only uses IE6 internally). Testing on IE Tester, the admin page is not usable. It works, but things are positioned off the screen, some boxes are pushed down 1000+ pixels, etc.

I can't find any mention of this elsewhere, so I'm wondering if it's a problem with IE Tester or Wordpress IE6-compatibility. I know WP dropped IE6-support, but I'm surprised that I can't find any plugins or solutions through a quick Google search.

What is one to do in this situation?

Comment: Download and install the last version of WordPress that had ie6 support. You will be without new features but it will work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IE6 is dead to WordPress since 3.2. You need to get 3.1 or earlier from the release archive: http://wordpress.org/download/release-archive/